# Second php script does not respond until the first have finished executing

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have 2 php files querying a single database. i have observed that when the first script is running and when you hit the url of the second script, the second page does not load until the first one finishes processing.

Sometimes the second script might even timeout with 'page not found' error if the first script takes too long.

What might be the reason for this? Doesnt mysql/php support mutiple scripts firing on a single table at once.

Am confused. Need some expert help.

Comment: Any table locks / database transactions involved in the first page?

Comment: What queries are you running? What database engine on the MySQL table? (Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on each table and look for the line containing `ENGINE=`)

Comment: am using innodb database. No I havent put any locks on db...simple db queries only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sessions? The default file-based session handler locks the session file while the script is running, until such time as the script ends, or you do a `session_write_close()`. While the session file is locked, no other page that uses sessions can start up.